# Can I not do this? Getting an 'exception' error

Tags: java, error-handling

Getting the following error: ".Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
"

```
    // Creates 10 accounts
         Account[] AccArray = new Account[10];
// Data fields
        double atmVal;

// Sets each account's discrete id and initial balance to 100
         for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            AccArray[i].setId(i); // this line is specified in the error
            AccArray[i].setBalance(100);
         }
```

This compiled fine, but I get an "exception" (not sure what those are, yet).

I don't see what's wrong at all, at least not here. If that's deemed to be the case, I'll add more of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is already intialized to contain 10 accounts, but they are all still null. Change your loop to be:

```
 for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        ArrArray[i] = new Account(); // whatever constructor parameters are needed
        AccArray[i].setId(i); // this line is specified in the error
        AccArray[i].setBalance(100);
     }
```

That being said I recommend you name your variables with lowercase names (e.g. `accArray`).

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array of objects, all you get is an array with the correct size but full of  `null`s. You need to create each object by saying `new Account()` and assigning it to the array. You can even do it in the same loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate an `Account`, assuming you have an empty constructor `Account` you'd use something like this -

```
 for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
   AccArray[i] = new Account(); // <-- like so.
   AccArray[i].setId(i); // this line is specified in the error
   AccArray[i].setBalance(100);
 }
```

Also, you should try and follow Java naming conventions... so maybe something more like,

```
Account[] accounts = new Account[10];

 for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
   accounts[i] = new Account(); // <-- like so.
   accounts[i].setId(i); // this line is specified in the error
   accounts[i].setBalance(100);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, creating a new array of `Account` doesn't actually create any `Accounts`; you have to do it yourself with `new`.  Java 8 gives you a nice way to do this:

```
Account[] accounts = new Account[10]; 
Arrays.setAll(accounts, i -> new Account());
```

The second parameter to `setAll` is a lambda expression that takes an integer parameter `i` (the index of the element being set) and sets array element to `new Account()`.  The expression doesn't actually use the index, but you could use an expression (or a block) that does use `i` if you want.