# Mutator methods with an Array of Objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

So i have an array of Room objects, the reason its static is because I'm doing it in main.

```
private static Room[] rooms = new Room[6];
```

So in my room class, i have a method called setStatus which sets a string to the room object

```
public String setStatus(String answer) {
if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Available") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Occupied")
            || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Needs cleaning (unavailable)")
            || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("For walk-ins")
            || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("For emergencies")) {
        this.status = answer;
        return status;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Status must be set to Available, Occupied or Needs cleaning (unavailable)");
        return null;
    }

}//end of setStatus
```

Now i want to set the status for each position in the array

```
rooms[random.nextInt(6)].setStatus("For walk-ins");
```

**However i get a nullpointer exception when i set the status of the array, any ideas?.**

Comment: I think someone just asked a similar question about an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050331/can-i-not-do-this-getting-an-exception-error/23050640#23050640

Comment: Are you sure your array (`rooms`) is populated with `Room` objects? Also, what if I pass `null` to your `setStatus()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the reason [`rooms`] static is because I'm doing it in main.

This is not your only choice - you could have declared it as a local variable inside the `main` method.

> However i get a null pointer exception

This is because you have initialized the array object, but you have forgotten to initialize its individual elements. You need to add a loop, and create each room individually.

If you keep `rooms` static, add a static initialization block, like this:

```
static {
    for (int i = 0 ; i != rooms.length ; i++) {
        rooms[i] = new Room(); // You may need to pass other parameters to the constructor
    } 
}
```

If you prefer to change `rooms` to a local variable, you can put the `for` loop in your `main`, immediately after the declaration / initialization of the `rooms` array object.